# How to loop until the program was stopped

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to make a program that is similar to a stopwatch, but not exactly. I am programming on https://www.online-python.com on a Chromebook. I want the program to just count up by 0.02 until the process or terminal is stopped.

#### Code

Whenever I try running the code, it does not carriage return correctly. My desired output is for the program to count up on a single line until the program is stopped, and then it stops counting. I also want it to go to 1.00 when the counter reaches 0.60.

```
import time

def mindseCOUNTING():
    mindse = 0
    while mindse > -1:
        time.sleep(0.02)
        format_float = "{:.2f}".format(mindse)
        print(f"{format_float}", end = "\r")
        mindse += 0.02

mindseCOUNTING()
```

Current output:

```
>>> 0.02
>>> 0.04
>>> 0.06
>>> 0.08
>>> 0.10
>>> 0.12
```

Is there a pattern or module to make a while loop that keeps looping until the program is stopped?

Comment: Try running it in an actual console window.

Comment: What is wrong with it right now? Any errors? What do you expect the code to do? Please [edit] and update.

Comment: I am currently using online-python.com on a Chromebook. Let me edit the question real quick and include that.

Comment: So you want to break out of the loop and run something else before exiting out of the program?

Comment: @jvx8ss I edited the question to answer your question. I forgot to clarify that.

Comment: @hc_dev Question edited and updated.

Comment: @KeiranHaas "I want the program to just count up by 0.02 until the process or terminal is stopped." But if you close the program the loop will stop. My guess is that you actually want to run something extra before exiting the program. is that correct?

Comment: @KeiranHaas The output you show seems quite like the one you describe as expected. And I get the same when I run your code in python-online: it counts until I stop the program. So please give an example of your desired output and how would it be different than the actual output.

Comment: @jvx8ss No. That is all I want.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Question edited and updated.

Comment: @KeiranHaas now its clearer, it doesn't output in the same line because https://www.online-python.com/ console doesn't support carriage return

Comment: Can anyone recommend an online Python compiler that **DOES** support carriage returns? The main websites I use are https://online-python.com and https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/, but they do not support carriage returns.